# Access a Shape inside another one in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have big shapes on my worksheet (a group of shapes), and inside everyone of them others little shapes (the blue rectangles),

[image]

I made a for loop for inside each Big shape to fill automatically the little shapes, but how can I loop over the Big ones, because all the big shapes are similars, and they have the same names for the littles shapes inside ?

How can I acces the little shape from the big one ?

I tried this but didn't worked

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(gr).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(x)).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Format(Range(y_1).Value, "#,##0") & " k" & Chr(13) & Format(Range(y_2).Value, "#,##0.00") & " DT"
```

The "gr" variable takes every time the name of the big shapes (Graph_1 .. Graph_5)
and the x variable takes the name of the little shapes inside (rect_1 .. rect_21)

I think this code does not help because my approach it's like how to access a case in an array if I can say ?

```
For Each myshape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
```

Comment: you'd better post both the code with which you're adding _big_ and _little_ shapes and some images of them too

Comment: done. the big shape is a group of shapes, inside of it, a list of shapes

Comment: what about the code that creates (and group) them?

Comment: it's one graph, I grouped it in PowerPoint, then paste it special in the worksheet 5 times (I have 5 big shapes, 5 groups). One sulotion is to name all the little shapes and make a loop, but  I just want to rename the little shape inside on group and then loop over the groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access child shapes inside a group by using following example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim shp             As Shape
    Dim shpChild        As Shape

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
            '/ Found a group. List all the child shapes here.
            For Each shpChild In shp.GroupItems
                Debug.Print "Child name :" & shpChild.Name & " Group name : " & shp.Name
            Next
         Else
            '/ No group. Individual shape.
             Debug.Print shp.Name
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Here... you should have figured it out yourself :)

[image]

```
Sub test()

    Dim shp             As Shape
    Dim shpChild        As Shape

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoGroup And shp.Name = "A" Then
            '/ Found a group called "A". List all the child shapes here.
            For Each shpChild In shp.GroupItems
                If shpChild.Name = "X" Then
                    '/ Found X.
                    shpChild.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Hello from VBA!!!"
                End If
            Next
         Else
            '/ No group. Individual shape.
             Debug.Print shp.Name
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't worked for my situation.
I just need to know simply how to get acces to a shape into a group of shapes, cause there are groups that I won't modify and also some shapes.

Comment: What should I add to this line of code if I want to modifiy the sahpe 'x' into the group 'Y', ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(x)).Select ?

Comment: didn't get your point. See the code, its accessing everything. Sorry if you are looking for a tailor made solution/code. :)

Comment: ok thanks any way for the help :) my point is clear, suppose I have two shapes named 'x' and 'y' into a group named 'A', how can I acces the shape 'x' within the group 'A', just simple as this :)